# preparedstatement.executeupdate() not working

Tags: java

```
try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DBManager.getStatement(updateQuery);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "xmlDesc");
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, 11666);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "xmlCode");
            System.out.println("before update");
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("after update");
} catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is my update Query:

```
updateQuery = update jde_status set jde_status_desc = ?, date_modified = sysdate, mod_by = ? where jde_status_code = ?;
```

It is not showing any error. But values are not gettin updated and am not seeing the sysout statement(after update) in console. The program is not terminating.

Comment: is there an error happening in your catch block too that is stopping that e.printStackTrace() from being printed perhaps, what happens if you just output a simple string instead? does that get displayed...?

Comment: please share the logs and which database you are using

Comment: How big is the jde_status table?  I could be that the query is just slow.  Try running your query from another DB client tool.

Comment: Is autocommit on the connection? Else you should commit.